# Can I add checkbox in iframe in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have list of checkbox which are loaded dynamically. These checkboxes are around 2000 CheckBox. Once they are loaded, the web page becomevery long and the shape is not good. I want to add these check box in frame so only frame will be extended and the size of the page will be the same. Any idea how to do so.

I tried to use iframe but what I see is that it can handle only either another web page or some document.

Comment: No, it is possible to dynamically code new documents inside an iframe. But you don't need an iframe; just use a `div` (or similar) with `overflow: auto` and a fixed height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `<iframe>` or `<frame>` is not needed. You can use CSS to do you what you are after.

Sample below should be easy to adapt to your needs.

```css
.div-that-scrolls {
  height:120px;
  overflow-y:auto;
  line-height:32px;
}
```

```html
<div>
List of checkboxes<br />
<div class="div-that-scrolls">
<input type="checkbox" id="i1" name="i1" /><label for="i1">Item 1</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i2" name="i2" /><label for="i2">Item 2</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i3" name="i3" /><label for="i3">Item 3</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i4" name="i4" /><label for="i4">Item 4</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i5" name="i5" /><label for="i5">Item 5</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i6" name="i6" /><label for="i6">Item 6</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i7" name="i7" /><label for="i7">Item 7</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i8" name="i8" /><label for="i8">Item 8</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i9" name="i9" /><label for="i9">Item 9</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i10" name="i10" /><label for="i10">Item 10</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i11" name="i11" /><label for="i11">Item 11</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i12" name="i12" /><label for="i12">Item 12</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i13" name="i13" /><label for="i13">Item 13</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i14" name="i14" /><label for="i14">Item 14</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i15" name="i15" /><label for="i15">Item 15</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i16" name="i16" /><label for="i16">Item 16</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i17" name="i17" /><label for="i17">Item 17</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i18" name="i18" /><label for="i18">Item 18</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i19" name="i19" /><label for="i19">Item 19</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i20" name="i10" /><label for="i10">Item 10</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i21" name="i21" /><label for="i21">Item 21</label><br />
<input type="checkbox" id="i22" name="i22" /><label for="i22">Item 22</label><br />
</div>
<p>
Something after the checkboxes
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank very much. This is exactly what I am looking for.